# Unable to connect to MongoDB Atlas from spring boot app deployed in azure

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, mongodb-atlas, azure-webapps

1. I deployed a spring boot app in Azure and have the below property in application.properties.
   **spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb+srv://*username*:*password*@cluster0-host.azure.mongodb.net/test?ssl=true**
2. I did a nslookup myapp-rest-api.azurewebsites.net -> fetched the ip address and added in mongodbAtlas  IPWhitelist.
3. When I hit a endpoint exposed by the app deployed on azure(this endpoint fetches the data from mongoDB Atlas). I get the below error:

2020-04-17T16:13:09.562280844Z: [INFO]  org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches com.mongodb.Mongo$4@48dc8d35. Client view of cluster state is {type=REPLICA_SET, servers=[{address=cluster0-shard-00-02-40bvf.azure.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}, {address=cluster0-shard-00-01-40bvf.azure.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}, {address=cluster0-shard-00-00-40bvf.azure.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}]; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches com.mongodb.Mongo$4@48dc8d35. Client view of cluster state is {type=REPLICA_SET, servers=[{address=cluster0-shard-00-02-40bvf.azure.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}, {address=cluster0-shard-00-01-40bvf.azure.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}, {address=cluster0-shard-00-00-40bvf.azure.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}]

Can someone help me resolve this issue ?

Comment: Just for a quick test, add `0.0.0.0/0` to your whitelist.  If it can connect then, it must be a different address.

Comment: Thank you @Joe! It worked :) Please let me know how do i check the ip address of the app on azure??

Comment: To find the outbound IP addresses currently used by your app in the Azure portal, click Properties in your app's left-hand navigation. They are listed in the Outbound IP Addresses field.